# I have two processes of same name in task manager with different path, I have to stop one of them, How to do that ?Please provide command in detail

Tags: batch-file

Currently I am using these commands to stop and start JAVA.exe

```
echo start stop wildfly                                 >>.\Restart_wildfly.log
echo Datum = %date% %time%                              >>.\Restart_wildfly.log
taskkill /F /IM java.exe                                >>.\Restart_wildfly.log
timeout 20 >nul                                         >>.\Restart_wildfly.log
echo start wildfly                                      >>.\Restart_wildfly.log
net start "Wildfly"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have use the above commands that I have posted in comment section but by using that it stops both the processes but I need to stop only one.

Answer (score 1):

The post
[taskkill to differentiate 2 images by path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524303/taskkill-to-differentiate-2-images-by-path)
suggests several methods to kill by full-path rather than by image-name:

Use PowerShell :

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.Path.StartsWith('C:\Dir1') }).Terminate()
```

Use WMIC :

```
wmic process where ExecutablePath='C:\\Dir1\\image.exe' delete
```

Comment: It's better to use `Get-CimInstance` as it has superseded `Get-WmiObject` for a number of Powershell versions. You can also use `Get-Process` instead of `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process`. But you will need to use `Kill` or pipe to `Stop-Process`.

Comment: (wmic process where ExecutablePath='C:\\Dir1\\image.exe' delete): What does this delete do? It is only killing the process or deleting any data?

Comment: Delete kills the process. Data loss may only occur because of loss of in-memory data of the process, but disk data is untouched (files that were in the process of being written but were not closed may be lost also).